# should I use relays?

Tags: relay, power-electronics

I am using attiny85 to control 4 motors that work all togather at the same time.
Will that hurt the attiny85 controller or is it ok. Because I think that the 4 motors will draw high power through the attiny85 and that may affect it. 
So should I use relay at this situation?

Comment: What kind of motors are you trying to drive?

Comment: Do the motors only turn in one direction?

Comment: Top tip never drive any motor through a microcontroller or any IC that's meant to deal with logic and not meant for motors. You could use a transistor if you want to control multiple motors at once but watch for the heat as you may need a heatsink. Or more simply just use a relay.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will need some sort of motor controller. The absolute maximum current draw from each pin of the ATTiny is 40 mA.

While it's possible to do this with relays, your best bet will be a set of H-bridge motor drivers.